# How to make my screen to listen to drag listener, android

Tags: android, android-viewpager, drag, gesture, ontouchlistener

I was trying to implement a drag down listener on my android app, and make a layout which is in view.GONE state animate and increase upto certain height as I drag down.

I tried using OnTouchListener Action Down and Action Up but it is not helping me.

How to achieve this?

Layout1(App_Header)

Layout2(MapView)

Layout3(ViewPager)

Layout 2 is hidden(View.GONE) after pressing a button.

now by dragging down the screen from the header I should get back my Layout2(MapView) increasing its height as I drag down.

I also tried using DragListener to PagerTabStrip on Layout 3, but it didn't work.

Are there any one who can help me on this?

Answer (score 2):

The best way to achieve it is using `OnTouchListener` and a custom `OnDragListener`.

[Here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidDragAndDrop/article.html) is a great example and [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html) is another one (from google documentation)

If you need any additional help just ask!

Comment: OnTouchListener doesn't help, because the height of the layout which I wanted to implement is too small

Comment: can you put some screenshots and/or code so your question is more complete and we can help you?